# How to say I fulfill the requirements with the word "satisfy"?

Tags: word-usage

I am applying to a job and I want to write a letter expressing that I'm the one they are looking for. I want to use the word *satisfy* but I don't know how to use it properly. Neither "I satisfy" nor "I'm satisfied" seem to mean "your requirements satisfy me", which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I mistook the correct usage "I satisfy your requirements" with "I satisfy **with** your requirements".
2. "I satisfy with your requirements", by itself, is a wrong use of "I'm satisfied with your requirements". I'm confused the former with the latter.
3. "I'm satisfied with your requirements", by itself, is weird in the meaning because we're only satisfied with the service or the manner that others ***giving*** us, although the sentence is grammatically correct.

So you either say "I satisfy your requirements" or "I'm satisfied with your service".

<sup>Related: [Can one meet criteria, or satisfy requirements?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67349/80007)</sup>